# Searching for a word/phrase in a string with all the possible approximations of the phrase

Tags: python, regex, full-text-search, fuzzy-search, fuzzywuzzy

Suppose I have the following string:

```
string = 'machine learning ml is a type of artificial intelligence ai that allows software applications to become more accurate at predicting outcomes without being explicitly programmed to do so machine12 learning algorithms use historical data as input to predict new output values machines learning is good'
```

Further suppose that I have a tag defined as:

```
tag = 'machine learning'
```

Now I wish to find the tag in my string. As you can see from my `string` there are three places that I have `machine learning`, one at the beginning of the `string` and one as `machine12 learning` and the last one as `machines learning`. I wish to find all of these and make an output list as

```
['machine learning', 'machine12 learning', 'machines learning']
```

To be able to do this I was tried to tokenize my tag using nltk. That is

```
tag_token = nltk.word_tokenize(tag)
```

I would then have `['machine','learning']`. I would then search for `tag[0]`.

I know that `string.find(tag_token[0])` and `data.rfind(tag_token[0])` would give the position of `machine` for the first and last finds, but what if I had more `machine learning` within the text (here we have 3)?

In that case I would not be able to extract them all. So my original idea to find all the occurrences of `machine` and then `learning` would have failed. I wished to use `fuzzywuzzy` to then analyze the `['machine learning', 'machine12 learning', 'machines learning']` with respect to the tag.

So my question is given then `string` I have, how can I search for the tag and its approximations and list them as follow?

```
['machine learning', 'machine12 learning', 'machines learning']
```

---

**Update:** I now know that I can do the followings:

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(machine[\s0-9]+learning)",re.IGNORECASE)
matches = pattern.findall(data)
#[output]: ['machine learning', 'machine12 learning']
```

also if I do

```
pattern = re.compile(r"(machine[\sA-Za-z]+learning)",re.IGNORECASE)
matches = pattern.findall(data)
#[output]: ['machine learning', 'machines learning']
```

But certainly, this is not a generalizable solution as it stands. So I wonder if there is a smart way to search in such scenarios?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe use pattern like this (string\w*)?

```
import re

string = 'machine 12 learning ml is a type of artificial intelligence ai that allows software applications to become more accurate at predicting outcomes without being explicitly programmed to do so machine12 learning algorithms use historical data as input to predict new output values machines learning is good'

tag_token=['machine','learning']

pattern='('+''.join(e+'\w*\s+(?:\S*\s+)?' for e in tag_token)[:-14]+')'

rgx=re.compile(pattern,re.IGNORECASE)
rgx.findall(string)
#output
#['machine 12 learning', 'machine12 learning', 'machines learning']
```

it will be more difficult to find matches with the changing position of words in the tag

and this code will **find all combinations** from **tag_token**. E.g.
`machine s learning` and `machine learning` and `machine12 12    learning` and `learning machine` ... Also you can create new string and new tag_token that containing more than 2 words. All combinations of these words will be found.

Example `tag_token = ['1', '2', '3']` will match `1 2 3` and `1a 2 b 3` and `2b2 1sss 3` and `333 2tt 1`

```
import re
import itertools

string = 'machine 12 learning ml is a type of artificial intelligence ai that allows software applications to become more accurate at predicting outcomes without being explicitly programmed to do so machine12 learning algorithms use historical data as input to predict new output values machines learning is good. Learning machine can be used to train people. learning the machines is a great job'

tag_token=['machine','learning']

pattern='('
for current_tag in itertools.permutations(tag_token, len(tag_token)):
    pattern+=''.join(e+'\w*\s+(?:\S*\s+)?' for e in current_tag)[:-14]+'|'

pattern=pattern.rstrip('|')+')'
rgx=re.compile(pattern,re.IGNORECASE)

rgx.findall(string)

#output
#['machine 12 learning', 'machine12 learning', 'machines learning', 'Learning machine', 'learning the machines']
```

Comment: Thank you @arutar. This is very interesting. I'm thinking of more general cases suppose we have 2+ words, or cases like `'machine 12 learning'` or `'machine s learning'` (basically with something extra in the middle of 2 words). I wonder how one can handle that? any suggestion?

Comment: the lower or capital wouldn't matter much as in the preprocessing I am lowercasing everything.

Comment: @Wiliam This example will work great for 2+ words. If you want to change find string, then regex improvement is necessary to something similar to ‘machine s learning’

Comment: @Wiliam I changed examples to match them to the strings like this 'machine 12 learning', also you can play with **string** and **tag_token**. Second example will **find all combinations** of strings inside tag_token (more than 2 words)

Comment: @Wiliam These are just simple examples and can be tailored to suit your needs. Just change the regex to the new one you want. Of greater interest is the second option with words combinations.

Comment: this is pretty neat :)